# Abnormal PHP string length and when searching Elasticsearch using PHP

Tags: php, string, elasticsearch, substr, strlen

I got abnormal PHP string from Elasticsearch.

step 1: `php curl` to invoke elastic search to get result `$value`,

step 2: `php $value2 = strip_tags($value); // to remove all html tags`

step 3: `var_dump($value2)`

step 4: `echo 'len='.mb_strlen($value2);`

step 5: `echo 'substr='.mb_substr($value2);`

step 3 Output is:

> string(974) " Ginger Never believe diet can help with cancer, but nice
>   try. 2018-01-22 11:20:21 Gland Totally no snacks? there must be some
>   snacks on the list, right... 2018-01-22 10:25:32 Reloated Article: How
>   to Treat Bladder Cancer with Diet?"

step 4 output is:

> len=974

step 5 output is:

> Empty string

Problem:

1. The total number of chars is about 231. Obviously less than 974.
2. `mb_strlen($value2) = 974`, when replace `mb_strlen` with `strlen`, get the same 974
3. when invoke `php mb_substr($value2)`, return empty string. use substr, get the same empty string.

What is the reason and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: I think it may convert some of the characters to ASCII. Try   `strlen(utf8_decode($value2));`  or  `mb_strlen($value2, 'UTF-8');` It must be some encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I fix it.
The real text of string contains lots of space char, and they are not rendered in browser. Remove them and everything is OK.